# Sequential element is unused and will be removed from module in vivado

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx, synthesis, vivado

I am getting a warning that says [Synth 8-3332] Sequential element (\i_data_1_vect_1_reg[31] ) is unused and will be removed from module cg_top in vivado. But the simulation is working fine. I would be great if someone shares why these warnings occur even though I am using these registers and how to solve it.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Comment: The warning states exactly what it means. Your particular register/sequential element is not being used in design. RTL simulation might be working for some other reason. You can maybe explain more on how you are "using" these regs

Comment: This may be better suited to https://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Iam using these registers in my module. This register is acutally connected to an input port of an IP that I instantiated in the module. Iam checking for a flag and according to the value of flag iam assigning values to this register.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities:
The register is not needed and hence can be removed. The most common reasons for that are:

- The output is not used.
- The output always has the same value and can be replaced with a constant 1 or 0.
- There is another (often adjacent) register which always has the same value and thus the output of that one is replicated.

Unfortunately there are some *rare* cases where Vivado reports removal, but actually nothing is removed. The only way to find out for certain is to open the synthesised design and check the schematic (visually, which may take you a long time) if the register has indeed been removed.
As I said these are *rare* cases. if your are inexperienced with HDL my money is that the register really is not needed.

Whatever the message, I have always found that the actual generated logic was correct.

Comment: I checked the schematic. Vivado is removing these registers. This register is actually connected to an input port of an IP that I instantiated in the module. I am checking for a flag and according to the value of flag iam assigning values to this register.

Comment: That is what I predicted: it is not needed. But without giving us code or a magic crystal ball we can't help you.